# How do Generate a random number between 1 and 2 in PHP

Tags: php, random

How do Generate a random number between 1 and 2 with a possible result of both integer or float in PHP

I try to use rand(1,2) or mt_rand(1,2) but i keep getting between 1 and 2.
I want my result so be either 1.3 , 1.1, 1.3 ,2

Comment: Since you seem to only want increments of 0.1, `mt_rand(10,20) / 10`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

What about this with `mt_rand()` and `mt_getrandmax()`?

```
<?php    
function randomFloat($min = 0, $max = 1) {
    return number_format($min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min), 2, '.', ''); // 2 decimal places
}

echo randomFloat(1,2);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/5a5U1